# Dual boot Ubuntu 20.10 and create partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.10

I have Ubuntu (20.10) installed and want to install windows 10 alongside but can't create a new partition or resize my only disk (Filesystem root). So is there a way to install Windows without uninstalling ubuntu? Or how can I create new partition.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS system? UEFI or BIOS install of Ubuntu? Post this:`sudo parted -l` Windows only installs in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives and only in BIOS mode to MBR(msdos) partitioned drives. How you boot install media is then how it installs. And with UEFI /gpt Windows wants multiple partitions. And in BIOS mode will only install to primary NTFS partition with boot flag.

Comment: @oldfred Its UEFI System

Comment: If UEFI and gpt partitioned drive, just make unallocated space and boot Windows installer in UEFI boot mode. Be sure to have good backups, but it should just work. It will make Windows the default boot, but you can change with efibootmgr or UEFI settings. And you still must turn Windows fast start up off, if you want to boot Windows from grub.